# Unable to catch an Exception from Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I am following this [MSDN guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle the exceptions within a Task.

This is what I wrote:

```
var myTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception("test");
    });
try
{
    myTask.Wait();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

I have set a breakpoint within the `catch` block, but at debug runtime, the code does not reach the breakpoint, and it's giving me:

> Exception is unhandled by user code

I have no idea what is going on as I have followed very closely to the example from the MSDN guide. In fact, I copied the example to my project and it's still giving the same problem.

Is there any method I can handle the exception outside the Task? I need to return a boolean value based on the fact if the task throws any Exception or not.

### Edit

To make it clearer for some of you, this is a more complete set of codes:

```
public bool ConnectToService()
{
    try
    {
        // Codes for ServiceHost etc etc, which I'm skipping
        // These codes are already commented out for this test, so they do nothing

        var myTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Supposed to connect to a WCF service, but just throwing a test exception now to simulate what happens when the service is not running
                throw new Exception("test");
            });
        try
        {
            myTask.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        // Other irrelevant stuff
        if (ConnectToService())
        {
            DoAnotherThing();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

}
```

I would also want to point out I have a solution for this, but it's puzzling why an example from MSDN isn't working for me. I would think that my own solution is not elegant, so I'm still looking for a more elegant solution.

```
Exception taskException = null;
var myTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("test");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskException = e;
        }
    });
try
{
    myTask.Wait();
    if (taskException != null) throw taskException;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the code, as you have shown, should definitely reach catch block. Are you using the same code or it is just demonstration of larger code?

Comment: @RohitGarg It's part of a big project, but for troubleshooting purposes, I have used the exact same code shown (or from example), but somehow it's not reaching the catch block.

Answer (score 4):

When a task is run, any exceptions that it throws are retained and re-thrown when something waits for the task's result or for the task to complete

```
task.Wait()  Rethrows any exceptions

task.Result  Rethrows any exceptions
```

As well, your code works correctly

Just press f5 while catching an exception and you will see that will get your point

Comment: This is what the MSDN article is implying, but apparently it's not doing that for me.

Comment: This comment saved me tons of research.

Answer (score 1):

According [to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) Task.Run:

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work.

So You throwing your exception on different thread than you trying to catch it. You should deal with exception on same thread.

Alternatively you can deal with unhandled exceptions in global [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

Jai, as mentioned, this code will always work. I think you will have to enable some settings in visual studio. The setting is turned off and because of this, you are getting "Exception not handled by user code".

try checking Under Tools, Options, Debugging, General, Enable just my code.

Also, you can use something like below if you don't like to bother about try/catch stuff :

```
myTask.ContinueWith(<you can access Exception property here to see if there was an exception>)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Problem and solved with ContinueWith

See:

```cs
var task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    ChatHubWrapper chatHub = Ordem_ServicoBLL.sendMensagemIniciarChatPelaVr(pessoaWrapper.OrdemServico);

                    foreach (var mensagem in chatHub.MensagensEnviadas)
                        ChatHub.sendMensagemTodaSala(pessoaWrapper.OrdemServico.ID, mensagem);
                })
                .ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted)
                        setPanelErrorWhats(t.Exception.InnerException.Message); // or throw new Exception...
                });

                task.Wait();

                if (task.IsCompleted)
                    Response.Redirect(pessoaWrapper.OrdemServico.getUrlViewOSSuporte());
```

With this you Don't need a create Exception taskException = null;

And is not good to use catch Inside Task.Run

Comment: You haven't specified the `scheduler` parameter, so the continuation will run on the `TaskScheduler.Current`. This is probably not what you want. You can check out these links: [1](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html "ContinueWith is Dangerous, Too"), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008 "CA2008: Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler").

Comment: Also, since the problem of this question is related with the Visual Studio debugger and not with the actual executable when it's running independently by the .NET runtime, I think that a proper solution would involve configuring the debugger, instead of trying to "fix" perfectly correct and valid code.

Answer (score -2):

@Jai, please try to move a Task.Run to the inside of try/catch block. I think Task.Run executes imediatelly so you may get exception because of that.

Comment: Actually, I have a try/catch on many levels. There is one surrounding the whole content of the method, there is one surrounding the caller of the method, and there is one surrounding shown in the example.

Comment: We dont see the rest of your app so only this one code part you pasted in the question. So could you move this line to the try block? We will eliminate possibly one reason. Then we will see.